# Angular HighCharts ParlimentChart is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Hello I am trying to use Parliment chart for highchart in angular. This link is about [js](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/parliament-chart)  but I want to use it in angular. In html

```
  <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" [(update)]="updateFromInput" [oneToOne]="oneToOne"></highcharts-chart>
```

in component

```
Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  updateFromInput = false;
  chartOptions = {
    chart: { type: 'item'},title: { text: ''},subtitle: { text: ''},
    legend: {labelFormat: '{name} <span style="opacity: 0.7">{y}</span>'},
    series: [{
        keys: ['name', 'y',  'label'],
        dataLabels: { enabled: true, format: '{point.label}'},
        center: ['50%', '88%'], size: '170%', startAngle: -100,endAngle: 100,
        data: [
            ['The Left', 69,  'DIE LINKE'],
            ['Social Democratic Party', 153, 'SPD']
        ],
    }]
  };
```

when i run it give error below

ERROR

> Error: Highcharts error #17:
> [www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=item](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=item)
>
> - missingModuleFor: item

How can I run parliment chart in angular. This is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnxscw?file=src/app/app.component.ts) which is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it with adding its chart js library. In this types charts in js file you can see that to run chart use

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/item-series.js"></script>
```

for angular part we need to import it from modules

```
import ItemSeries from 'highcharts/modules/item-series';
```

and then use `ItemSeries(Highcharts);` to accept it